# How to add multiple blocks to game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a simple breakout game like [this](http://pygame.org/shots/1170.png).
I am using HTML5 Canvas + JavaScript.

My problem is that I don't know how to add multiple blocks (efficiently).

I can add one; but I can't add another without having to change this:

```
var block = {
    width: 75,
    height: 20,
    x: 212,
    y: 0
};

ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
```

To this:

```
var block2 = {
    width: 75,
    height: 20,
    x: 300,
    y: 0
};
ctx.fillRect(block2.x, block2.y, block2.width, block2.height);
```

There must be a better way than manually creating new variables and using `ctx.fillRect` for every block in my game. If anyone could tell me how, I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Please check this JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/3hEJJ/1/

Comment: Please don't tag your question titles - that's what the proper tags are for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using object literals you can create an instanceable object which includes an self-updating method:

```
function Block(x, y, w, h) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.width = w;
   this.height = h;
}

Block.prototype.update = function(ctx) {
   ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height); 
};
```

Now you can create a bunch of objects:

```
var blocks = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // get the x,y ... from somewhere, f.ex. another array
    blocks.push(new Block(x, y, w, h));
}
```

To update then simply call:

```
for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].update(ctx);
}
```

Comment: nice approach. That's what I love about SO, you always learn something new.

Comment: I have tried to incorporate this into my code and I just can't get it working. I must be missing something obvious. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hEJJ/3/. Sorry if it is really stupid mistake, I am very new to coding and these concepts take a while for me to understand. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @user3672496 try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/3hEJJ/4/ For a single block of course only one var is needed (for many use array as in example). Replace the block var with the new object then simply call update on it in your render method. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Epistemex thank you for all the help! I have spent hours (literally hours) trying to understand this concept, and to be honest I just don't get it, maybe I'm not cut out for programming. I can get it to make one block; but not two. I just don't get the concept. But thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @user3672496 It's perhaps my explanation that isn't sufficient. You will have many a-ha experiences in this field (I know I had over the decades) so it's part of the "path to enlightenment" - but don't give up! :) SO is perhaps neither the right place for the most basic stuff as it assumes the basic understanding is already there. But play around with the code and see what happens when you change things around. Learning to code is a great deal about experimenting. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/3hEJJ/7/

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/3hEJJ/2/  Check this fiddle

You could go for Object arrays .

```
var blockArray=new Array();

blockArray.push({
    width: 75,
    height: 20,
    x: 212,
    y: 0
});
blockArray.push({
    width: 75,
    height: 20,
    x: 300,
    y: 0
});
blockArray.push({
    width: 70,
    height: 15,
    x: 230,
    y: 0
});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the jsfiddle to your example (although it doesn't work (?)). I will report back if I can get it to work (I am new to coding so I am slow to understand these concepts; it could take a while before I get this working).

Comment: +1 for a working fiddle, but you are still having to create the blocks one after the other, and I think that you would want a loop to do this  to avoid having a big piece of text to create the blocks

Comment: Sorry guys ,I was focusing more on answering  user3672496 question rather than making a working game module :).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a loop to create the blocks

so some pseudo code (my javascript isn't all that):

```
foreach (i=0; i< maxRows; i++)
{
  for (j=0; j< maxBlocksPerRow;j++)
   {
      AddBlock(GetXpos(i),GetYPos(j));
    } 
}

function AddBlock(xpos, ypos)
{
    var block = {
    width: 75,
    height: 20,
    x: xpos,
    y: ypos
    };

     ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
}
```

I'll leave the remaining functions as an exercise for the student.

You probably want to add the blocks you create to some collection so you can keep track of them though.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... your idea sounds good. Maybe I would instead define the ``AddBlock(i)`` function to explain how the position is setup according to the index of the block - setting coordinates for position.

Comment: the down votes were because I answered simply first then expanded the answer afterwards.  The downvotes were cast in the very first version of the answer. Hey ho.